# Dual booted Windows 10 with Ubuntu 19.10, secure boot turned on, Laptop won't turn on

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, amd-radeon

I dual booted my Lenovo IdeaPad 330 with ubuntu 19.10 and Windows 10 with secure boot off. While I was running Windows, BIOS update notification came up and I installed it. My Laptop ran extremely extremely slow after that. Then Windows stopped booting in 2 days, the logo would appear and then all animations will stop and no further progress will occur. Then I realised that the update had turned secure boot on. I disabled secure boot and still then performance degraded and Windows still won't boot. Now I was running Ubuntu full time with degraded performance. Then in 3 days multimedia keys of keyboard stopped working. And the next day, I closed laptop's lid, it went to sleep mode, then it never turned on again.

It has: Intel i5 8th gen, 8 gb RAM, AMD Radeon 530.

Now even BIOS settings won't open. Pressing laptop's on button does nothing except blinking of power LED.

So, even USB boot is impossible...

Comment: Thing to remember about BIOS - Don't fix it if it ain't broken !! May be the BIOS update messed up your PC. Take out the battery and try to power it on..does the fan spin...does the HDD spin ?? anything on the screen ?

Comment: @Elmo Did removed battery and tried booting, but of no help. Neither fan spins nor HDD spins, just power LED glows and then stops and reglows every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to open up your laptop.

Remove the battery and AC power adapter, open up the case and disconnect(take it out) the CMOS battery, holding the power button down for 30 seconds to fully drain the system.  Then reconnect the CMOS battery after 10 minutes , reconnect the AC power adapter, held Windows+V, held the power button for 5 seconds and released it but held Windows+V for another 10 seconds, and usual Windows 10 login screen should appear.

Comment: Did it, no benefit at all...

Comment: @EverydayHacker Sorry, I guess you will have to take it to the Lenovo service center.

Comment: Ya, I took it to Service Centre today, they say that the processor has failed. Applied for motherboard replacement. Laptop was out of warranty 

Comment: Ok, this thing happened again to friend's laptop, and this method worked. I think Ubuntu 19.10 does not ship with AMD GPU drivers. (Yet mine was a motherboard failure)